# Java - Sharing int values between cases in a switch statment

Tags: java

I'm new to java and not sure how do I share values between cases in a switch statement? When I try to use a variable which i created in the previous case it tells me "variable might not have been initialized"

Code:

```
case 6:
    String stringCopy = stringInput;
    String lowerCase = stringCopy.toLowerCase();
    int vowelCount = 0;
    int stringLength = lowerCase.length();

    for (int i = 0; i <= stringLength - 1; ++i){
        switch(stringInput.charAt(i)) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                vowelCount++;
        }
        System.out.println(vowelCount);
        break;
    }

case 7:
    int noofConstants = 0;
    noofConstants = (stringLength - vowelCount);
```

Comment: Please show code -- what do you mean by "sharing int values between cases..."

Comment: @Nasus Declare your variable before the switch

Comment: please provide more information for give better answer... and use `ctrl+k` to style your code...

Comment: But the value is created in the switch, is there no other way to do this?

Comment: `"But the value is created in the switch, is there no other way to do this?"` -- you need to explain why it can't be declared **before**.

Comment: You can't declare the same variable twice.  And the the compiler won't let you shoot yourself in the foot by letting you declare a variable in one case try to use it in another (where it won't exist if your switch had jumped straight to that case)

Comment: You should try looking at this code in IntelliJ... It will have some useful observations to point out to you, such as "`for` statement does not loop."

Answer (score 4):

Declare and initialize value **before** the switch statement.

```
  int value = 0;
  switch (key) {
  case 3:
     value = 1 + 1;
     break;
  case 4:
     value = 1;
     break;
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot access a variable that you initialize in a separate code block which is `case` .

declare it outside/before the code block

```
int stringLength = 0;

switch(){

  case 6:
     stringLength = 1;
  break;

  case 7:
      stringLength = 2;
  break;

}
```